# Doubt about font inclusion (GAMEMAKER)?

Tags: game-maker, fonts

The default font of the GameMaker is **arial**, but it does not contain special characters that are present in the **portuguese language**.

Soon I had to add a new font, but I activated the **ASCII** option so that the characters I needed were included.

[image]

Hence come my doubt: Even the new font being arial I need to enable the option **include in Asset Package** for the game to work properly?

[image]

And if I have to enable it, where I put the file, and more. Does it need to have a specific name?

Comment: No, you don't need it.

Comment: From the documentation: `There is also a check-box labelled "Include In Asset Package. If you are creating a package of fonts to upload to the Marketplace or to distribute as part of an extension, then you should tick this option otherwise the base font files will not be distributed with the package.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game Maker takes the fonts installed in the OS.
You should include your font in your asset package when it is a font you downloaded and is not present in other systems where the game is to be played. 
Anyway, what GM does is to create a PNG file with all the glyphs selected in the font properties in the same way as a sprite font.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thanks for answering. Did you mean to type 'OS' (operating system) or are you referring to something else in your first sentence?

Comment: Yes, I mistyped it, I speak spanish so I didn't realize I made a typo XD
now it's OK

Comment: Tu inglés es probablemente mejor que mi español :) Anyway, no worries, that's part of what the commenting & editing system are for. Had I been a little more certain, I would have made the edit myself. But I'm not familiar with GameMaker, and didn't know if SO referred to some internal feature.

Comment: Resumiendo entonces ... no tengo que marcar la opción porque arial es una fuente presente en prácticamente todos los ordenadores.